# VueJs: How to reuse bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-vue

I've created three simple buttons that will trigger three different bootstrap modal dialog. The modal dialogs are **"Add Product"**, **"Edit Product"** and **"Delete Product"**. Both the **Add** and **Edit**  modal dialogs contain a form with two input elements, whereas the **Delete** modal dialog contains a simple text. I realise that my code becomes very messy and hard to maintain. Hence, I have the following question:

1) How do I reuse the modal dialog, instead of creating 3 separate dialogs?

2) How do I know which modal dialog has been triggered?

**Update**:  I've developed a soultion where I will include **conditional statements such as v-if, v-else-if and v-else** to keep track of which button the user click. However, I still feel that there is a better solution to this. Can anyone help/advice me?

Below is my current code:

```
       <template>
  <div>
    <b-button v-b-modal.product class="px-4" variant="primary" @click="addCalled()">Add</b-button>
    <b-button v-b-modal.product class="px-4" variant="primary" @click="editCalled()">Edit</b-button>
    <b-button v-b-modal.product class="px-4" variant="primary" @click="deleteCalled()">Delete</b-button>

    <!-- Modal Dialog for Add Product -->
    <b-modal id="product" title="Add Product">
      <div v-if="addDialog">
        <form @submit.stop.prevent="submitAdd">
          <b-form-group id="nameValue" label-cols-sm="3" label="Name" label-for="input-horizontal">
            <b-form-input id="nameValue"></b-form-input>
          </b-form-group>
        </form>

        <b-form-group id="quantity" label-cols-sm="3" label="Quantity" label-for="input-horizontal">
          <b-form-input id="quantity"></b-form-input>
        </b-form-group>
      </div>

      <div v-else-if="editDialog">
        <form @submit.stop.prevent="submitEdit">
          <b-form-group id="nameValue" label-cols-sm="3" label="Name" label-for="input-horizontal">
            <b-form-input id="nameValue" :value="productName"></b-form-input>
          </b-form-group>
        </form>

        <b-form-group id="quantity" label-cols-sm="3" label="Quantity" label-for="input-horizontal">
          <b-form-input id="quantity" :value="productQuantity">5</b-form-input>
        </b-form-group>
      </div>

      <div v-else>
        <p class="my-4">Are You Sure you want to delete product?</p>
      </div>
    </b-modal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      productName: "T-Shirt",
      productQuantity: 10,
      addDialog: false,
      editDialog: false,
      deleteDialog: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addCalled() {
      this.addDialog = true;
    },
    editCalled() {
      this.editDialog = true;
      this.addDialog = false;
      this.deleteDialog = false;
    },
    deleteCalled() {
      this.deleteDialog = true;
      this.addDialog = false;
      this.editDialog = false;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Comment: I understand what you have, but what have you  tried yet ?. Put steps you think will work here. Totally a question where you want your job get done

Comment: Hi @SatyamPathak, I currently am working on a solution where I will include v-if statements in the modal dialog. However, it is not working, that's why I've decided to use this basic code instead

Comment: @SatyamPathak Do I still post it here?

Comment: Hi @SatyamPathak, I finally got my code to work. Please look at my updated post!

Comment: Hey look at my question, it is totally upto you as your question does not having non-working code instead you want a way to achieve. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentionned, I would have use slots and dynamic component rendering to accomplish what you're trying to do in a cleaner way.

See snippet below (I didn't make them modals as such but the idea is the same).

This way, you can have a generic `modal` component that deals with the shared logic or styles and as many `modalContent`sub-components as needed that are injected via the dedicated slot.

```js
Vue.component('modal', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <h1>Shared elements between modals go here</h1>
      <slot name="content"/>
    </div>
  `
});


Vue.component('modalA', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <h1>I am modal A</h1>    
    </div>
  `
});

Vue.component('modalB', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <h1>I am modal B</h1>    
    </div>
  `
});

Vue.component('modalC', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <h1>I am modal C</h1>    
    </div>
  `
});


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    modals: ['modalA', 'modalB', 'modalC'],
    activeModal: null,
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button v-for="modal in modals" @click="activeModal = modal"> Open {{ modal }} </button>
  <modal>
    <template slot="content">
      <component :is="activeModal"></component>
    </template>
  </modal>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply! You said that you would not make the modals as such. I was wondering what will be your approach, given my scenario?

Comment: I was not clear, sorry :  I just said that I didn't make my example components "modals" but regular divs, for the sake of the example. You can replace my dummy components with regular modals, the logic remains the same

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Now, You might think how will you close your modal and let the parent component know about it.
On click of button trigger `closeModal` for that

Create a method - `closeModal` and inside commonModal component and `emit` an event.

```
closeModal() { 
  this.$emit('close-modal')
}
```

Now this will emit a custom event which can be listen by the consuming component.

So in you parent component just use this custom event like following and close your modal

```
<main class="foo">
  <commonModal v-show="isVisible" :data="data" @close- modal="isVisible = false"/>
  <!-- Your further code -->
</main>
```

So as per your question

A - **How do I reuse the modal dialog, instead of creating 3 separate dialogs**

Make a separate `modal` component, let say - `commonModal.vue`.

Now in your `commonModal.vue`, accept single `prop`, let say `data: {}`.

Now in the `html` section of `commonModal`

```
<div class="modal">
  <!-- Use your received data here which get received from parent -->
  <your modal code />
</div>
```

Now import the `commonModal` to the consuming/parent component. Create data property in the parent component, let say - `isVisible: false` and a computed property for the `data` you want to show in `modal` let say `modalContent`.

Now use it like this

```
<main class="foo">
   <commonModal v-show="isVisible" :data="data" />
   <!-- Your further code -->
</main>
```

The above will help you re-use modal and you just need to send the `data` from parent component.

Now second question will also get solved here **How do I know which modal dialog has been triggered?**

Just verify `isVisible` property to check if `modal` is open or not. If `isVisible = false` then your modal is not visible and vice-versa

Comment: Hi @Satyam. Thank you for your reply, I have a question. Let's say at the "data" prop, I want to pass a form element that contains two input fields. How do I do that? I've never pass HTML code as a prop before, so this is new to me

Comment: why will you even pass an `html` element, put everything related to `modal` inside your `commonModal` component. Ok, if any case you still want the html to be sent by `parent` then use `slot`, have a look - https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Comment: Hi @Satyam, I am still confused. Given my code above, what data should I pass into the data prop, so that the contents in the modal dialog can be rendered dynamically and differently?